# SQL ResultSet into Pivot Table in Web Page

Tags: html, mysql, sql, pivot

I would like to know if there is any quick and efficient way to build a pivot table from a ResultSet object, I have to display the Pivot Table in an HTML page. I have seen some libraries online but they do not allow the data source to be a mySQL database. Thanks.

Comment: Datagrids maybe? This is a bit OT for SO

Comment: has to be a pivot table

Comment: What's the difference?